# Importing project into Firebase not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I have just tried importing a google project into Firebase.

When I press the button on the https://console.firebase.google.com/ page, my project is listed. I then pick the country, and press the "Add Firebase" button, the activity indicator spins and then stops.

The project is not added, and there's no message to say it has been added.

I added a project a few months ago. Has anything changed, has anyone done this recently?

Comment: It's going to be hard to help beyond the usual "disable all ad blockers" and "check the JavaScript console". If those don't help, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Did you fixed it? I have exactly same problem

Comment: I got it to work by doing it in a chrome incognito browser session

Answer (score 0):

After speaking to google support I got it to work in a chrome incognito browser session